# Unity iOS AR URP glowing and looks weird

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, arkit, ar-foundation

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svGM0.png)When we export our AR application with Unity, it looks like this. We use URP.

Which export setting should i set, and why? Can someone explain me.

I change all the setting from unity, lightmaps, shaders and ETC. Also added background renderer to pipeline. No changes. Its only works with build in pipeline but i need to use URP.